# Is there any way to color concrete words in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, bashrc

I would like to know if there is any way to color, in `.bashrc` for example, according to what words or what situations.

I explain myself: I want to color the IP addresses that appear on the console, I would also like to color all the error words in red, and also the first argument of each command (the name of the command itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what your looking for is `grc`, i.e [generic colorizer](https://github.com/garabik/grc). With it you'll be able to setup regexes thats matches your command/output to colors. And there is a bunch of predefined configuration too.